# Video File to Base64String issue in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have created a video recording feature in Windows Phone 8, and am converting byte array to a base-64 string. How do I get the duration of the recording? My byte array memory size becomes too large and therefore the base64String is also too big, so I am getting error like this:

```
"System.OutOfMemoryException"
```

for more information see my code below:

```
private IsolatedStorageFileStream isoVideoFile;
string isoVideoFileName = "CameraMovie.mp4";

isoVideoFile = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(isoVideoFileName,
                   FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                   IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
isoVideoFile.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Position);

byte[] binaryData = new Byte[isoVideoFile.Length];
long bytesRead = isoVideoFile.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)isoVideoFile.Length);
string videofile = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
```

For video length:

```
    private void Element_MediaOpened1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mediaElement_1.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
        timelineSlider.Maximum = mediaElement_1.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You get over per app [memory limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681682%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Try to dispose resources. It's good practice to use `using` with streams. Something like this:
    private IsolatedStorageFileStream isoVideoFile;
    string isoVideoFileName = "CameraMovie.mp4";

```
using(isoVideoFile = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(isoVideoFileName,
                   FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                   IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
{
    using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        isoVideoFile.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Position);
    }
    byte[] binaryData = new Byte[isoVideoFile.Length];
    long bytesRead = isoVideoFile.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)isoVideoFile.Length);
    string videofile = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
}
```

And what about video duration, here is [thread on msdn forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/6b64c92d-8c3d-43ba-a6dc-9ed49431659c/video-duration-downloaded-file-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: ad1Dima, thanks man, i am checking it and how do I get the video duration?thnx

Comment: ad1Dima, I am still getting error brother: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module."

Comment: ad1Dima, i just record for 2 seconds and still its size becomes in 7 digits.Please guide me.Thanks!!

Comment: @NiteshKothari sory, I can't help with this.

Comment: ad1Dima, ok bro, see my edited code for video length, I saw in forums, how do I define "timelineslider"?thank you!!